# Problems with qt library after update to ubuntu 15.10 from 15.04

Tags: 15.10, vlc, qt

After updating the os, some programs like `vlc` and `texmaker` don't work anymore.

`texmaker` gives me following error:

```
texmaker: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebugD1Ev
```

and `vlc`:

```
[00000000022f7e58] core interface error: corrupt module: /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
[00007f695002e888] core generic error: corrupt module: /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so 
[00000000022f7e58] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[00000000022f7e58] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[00000000022f7e58] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
```

VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax)

Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you originally install texmaker and vlc from the standard Ubuntu repositories, or from elsewhere?

Comment: from the standard repositories. i tried reinstalling but it didn't help

Comment: can anybody help?